# Sliver App Bar not displaying correctly - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I'm trying to display a SliverAppBar as shown on my design

[image: Design Screen Shot]

but I'm not sure it can be done in Flutter

here is my code so far

```
        SliverAppBar(
      // title: ,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      expandedHeight: 300,
      centerTitle: true,
      shape: const ContinuousRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(100))),
      actions: <Widget>[
CircleAvatar(
              radius: 20,
              // foregroundColor: Colors.red,
              backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                'assets/img/categories/player.png',
              ),
            ),
      ],
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        background: Container(),
        centerTitle: true,

        title: Container(
          height: 40,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text("Mrs Surname Name",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Kannada Sangam MN',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    // color: AppTheme.high_emphasis,
                  )),

            ],
          ),
        ),

      ),
      pinned: true,
      floating: false,
      elevation: 0,
    ),
```

I'd like for the name & Motif to show even when scrolled up also the Avatar but smaller

But the "Constantes" to hide when scrolled up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `SliverAppBar title` to hold `name & Motif` because it will be always visible to the UI. on Next part avatar image also be always visible but will reduce the size based on scroll, in this case putting it inside `flexibleSpace:FlexibleSpaceBar(title: Avatar)`  will be better choice. For others, info that will be vanished based on scroll, so we can use `FlexibleSpaceBar( background:)` for that and to populate it using `column`. But there will be overlap, and we can trick it using    `const SizedBox(height: kToolbarHeight,),` at 1st child of `Column`.

**Result**

[image]

[image]

Here is a sample that can help to produce the UI, you can tweak the decoration the way like.

```dart
      SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
            expandedHeight: 300,
            title: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: const [
                Text(
                  "Mrs, Surname Name",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Mrs, Surname Name",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 26,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            shape: const ContinuousRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(100),
              ),
            ),
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
               background: Container(
                color: Colors.grey[200],
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                child: Column(
                  ///* however we can use sizedBox to handle upperSpaces
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    ///* like this
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: kToolbarHeight,
                    ),
                    ...List.generate(
                      4,
                      (index) => Text("others info"),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              title: Row(
                ///* not sure why i cant avoid using Row here
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 70,
                      width: 70,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Colors.deepOrange,
                      ),
                      child: Text("img"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: thx so much for your help but in your code the img overlaps with the title - also I'd like to set status bar to false so it's same grey color but the image overlaps it when scrolled up 

Comment: Yes, that's a little issue while scrolling. but it's kinda faded, that's why I've ignored that

Comment: thank you I up voted could you help me with my other questions also on SliverAppBar ? : )

Comment: Feel free to include

Comment: [SliverAppBar Always Show Shadow - Expanded mode too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69489331/how-to-sliverappbar-always-show-shadow-expanded-mode-too) - [SliverAppBar hide list between SliverPersistentHeader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69492660/sliverappbar-hide-list-between-sliverpersistentheader) - thank you very much - the first one I need more help with 

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SliverOverlapAbsorber/SliverOverlapInjector.
Try [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html) hope it will work.

Comment: could you expand on how this would help please